# Can I choose network dynamically in hardhat?

Tags: web3js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I've written a REST API using a hardhat server. I need to send the network through the API parameter.

For example, currently, I've set the default network as **polygon** in config.hardhat.js, and it all is working fine. Now I need to enable my server to support two networks [Ethereum & Polygon] in runtime.

P.S. I know we can set multiple networks in config.hardhat.js. I need to select the network dynamically at runtime without restarting the server.

Comment: If you call scripts using the CLI tool you can pass something like `--network <network name>`

Comment: that is impossible i think......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this npm module that allows changing the network dynamically in Hardhat. This is a simple plugin that just changes a few lines in hardhat.config.js to change the network.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/hardhat-change-network